# Modifying a touch lamp to control a smart bulb

Tags: smart-switch, lamp

I have two (I think) inexpensive desktop/bedside touch lamps that I would like to integrate into a smart home. They work well enough if I just use smart bulbs in them until a cat touches them and they turn off. If a cat turns them on and off 3 times in a minute, the bulb resets.

I want to bypass the capacitive switch in the lamp so the bulb is always powered, but I still want to be able to touch the base to control the smart bulb (turn it off by command, not by pulling power). If I have seen switches that I can replace the built-in switch in the lamp base with that can be used for this purpose, I have not recognized them. How should I describe such a switch for the purposes of finding it?

(At the moment, I am open to using HomeKit, Caseta, or Zigbee devices.)

Comment: Wow, that is an ambitious project. Since you have the smart-home ecosystem (hub and all that stuff), you should probably rewire the light so always-hot and neutral bypasses all lamp internals and goes straight from plug to bulb socket, and then come up with a low-voltage/battery/USB-powered way of detecting finger-touch on that touch pad, and signaling that into the smart-home ecosystem.

Comment: Hue sells a zigbee device intended to connect to a wall switch. The idea is that you hardwire the light power to always on, then connect this hue device to the switch - which then shows up in the hue app and can be used to control lighting. I bet this could work inside your touch lamp, if wired correctly.

Comment: I've wired the lamps to be always on. The control circuitry of the touch lamps is glued in quite well. I've ordered a replacement touch control from amazon (about $8) to tear apart to see how it works.

Comment: I ultimately decided to just rewire these devices so the light is always on and use other controls because a cat kept pawing at the base of one of the lamps.